# List directory and find files with certain strings in the name

Tags: shell

I am fairly new to shell scripting, so go easy on me please as I know this is most likely something real basic. My question is this, I need to write a script that will look at a directory and tell me if it finds a match for a string that I specify in the filenames. Here would be an example.

I have a directory named tmp. Inside that directory are files named tmp-a, temp-a, temporary-a, etc. If the script looks at the directory and sees that there is a filename with the string of 'tmp', or 'temp' it should continue with the script, but if it does not see any filenames matching a string specified in the shell script it should quit. I am basically looking for a conditional 'if [ -f filename ]' statement that can apply 'or'.

I hope that made sense and as always, thanks in advance.

Tim

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. As stated above, it was easy. I never looked into the -e switch on grep. Sorry to waste your time. Thanks again and have a good day.

Comment: grep is no use here: you'd first have to feed it a list of file names (no, [`ls` is not the way](mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)), and both shell patterns and `find` can do pattern matching on the names, rendering grep useless.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern `tmp*` expands to the list of files whose name begins with `tmp`, or to the single-word list consisting of the literal pattern itself if there is no matching file.

```
set --
for pattern in 'tmp*' 'temp*'; do
  set -- $pattern "$@"
  if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then shift; fi
done
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No matching file"
else
  for x in "$@"; do …; done
fi
```

In bash, you can request the expansion of a pattern that matches no file to be the empty list, which simplifies matters a lot.

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- tmp* temp*
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then …
```

The same thing goes for zsh, which allows this to be set per-pattern.

```
set -- tmp*(N) temp*(N)
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then …
```

If you wish to search recursively inside directories, you can use the `find` command.

```
if [ -n "$(find -name 'tmp*' -o -name 'temp*' | head -c 1)" ]; then
  # there are matching files
fi
```